# How to pass arguments to anonymous PHP class constructor?

Tags: php

I wrote small anonymous class. now i want to pass some arguments to anonymous class . how could i accomplish this task . Currently i m using  `PHP 8.1` version

```
<?php

$myObject = new class {
    public function __construct($num)
    {
        echo 'Constructor Calling'.$num;
    }

    public function log(string $text){
        return $text;
    }

};


var_dump($myObject->log("Hello World"));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your class require $num argument in construct, you need to pass it when you instanciate your object.

```
<?php

$myObject = new class(1) {
    public function __construct($num)
    {
        echo 'Constructor Calling'.$num;
    }

    public function log(string $text){
        return $text;
    }

};


var_dump($myObject->log("Hello World"));
```

Will result

```
Constructor Calling1
string(11) "Hello World"
```